# Icon disappear after md-fab-toolbar collapse in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

*Icon disappear after md-fab-toolbar collapse in angular material*

```
<md-fab-trigger class="align-with-text">
                    <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-mini md-primary">
                        <i class="ion-plus"></i>
                    </md-button>
</md-fab-trigger>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it disappears is because AngularJS Material add a style to the button's icon which requires the `<md-icon>` element inside.

Updated code:

```html
<md-fab-trigger class="align-with-text">
    <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-mini md-primary">
        <md-icon style="display: unset">
            <i class="ion-plus"></i>
        </md-icon>
    </md-button>
</md-fab-trigger>`
```

Comment: According to [this demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/icon#font-icons-with-classnames), you should use the `md-font-icon` attribute to get an icon from an icon font. More info on setting up [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdIconProvider#mdiconprovider-defaultfontset-name)